# QT TcpServer Max clients

Tags: c++, qt, tcpserver

I want to use `setMaxPendingConnections` in my application. I've tried that code:

```
MainCLass::MainCLass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
  this->server = new QTcpServer(this);
  server->setMaxPendingConnections(2);
  QObject::connect(this->server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(newuser()));

  if (!this->server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 33333)) {
      qDebug() << "Error create server!";
  }


}

void MainCLass::newuser()
{
  qDebug() << "New client!";
  QTcpSocket* clientSocket=server->nextPendingConnection();
  clientSocket->write("Hello!");

  qDebug() << "Max connect?" << this->server->hasPendingConnections();

}
```

But it does not work. More than 2 clients is able to connected in my server. What's wrong? Where is mistake? I use Qt5. Tried on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12

Comment: That's the number of *pending* connections; once you handle once by calling `nextPendingConnection`, it's not pending any more and the pending connections counter gets decreased.

Comment: Oh...so how can I use limit for clients?

Comment: Do not call `nextPendingConnection` if you're already handling enough clients.